# Using Excel 2016 as database in ASP Classic

Tags: asp-classic, odbc, dsn, excel-2016

Does anyone know how I can display the content of an Excel 2016 file in a webpage?

I cannot figure out how to open a connection from the webpage nor which drivers I might need to install in order to open the ODBC or DSN connection.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you tried? Where have you looked? [Google seems to offer much](https://www.google.com/search?q=asp+odbc+excel)...

Comment: The JET OLEDB driver and the Excel ODBC driver are both included with Windows, but they're both 32 bit only - https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Comment: Does Jet work with XLSX files ?

Comment: Thank you for your coments TallTed, You got me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working after using a couple of hours on it.

Heres how I read the data out

```
<%
Dim Conn, Sql, rs
Set Conn = Server.createobject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\test.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";"

    ' Ark1 is danish for Sheet1
    Sql = "select * from [Ark1$]"

set rs = Conn.Execute(Sql)

do while not rs.eof or rs.bof
    response.write rs("test") & "<br>" & vbCrLf
    rs.movenext
loop

    Conn.CLose
Set Conn = nothing
%>
```

Hope this might help others.